# when applying styles to icons on fusion table, getting unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Have a map that I made using Google Maps API and Fusion Tables. I am trying to change the appearance of the markers on the map.

When I add the "styles", https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer my map will not load on the page, and I get an error in my console reading: "unexpected identifier - styles"

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var map, layer;
var geocoder;

function initialize(location) {

  console.log(location);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var userlocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: userlocation,
    zoom: 8
  });

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: '\'Geocodable address\'',
      from: '1x265dMvUClEGEVHD_3VRBvSRXk-mbs4jcO2xy29K',
    }
    styles: [
   {markerOptions:{ iconName:"star"}}
  ]                                        
  });
  layer.setMap(map);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're missing a comma before `styles`

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: '\'Geocodable address\'',
      from: '1x265dMvUClEGEVHD_3VRBvSRXk-mbs4jcO2xy29K',
    }, //need a comma here
    styles: [{...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a "," before styles:

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: '\'Geocodable address\'',
      from: '1x265dMvUClEGEVHD_3VRBvSRXk-mbs4jcO2xy29K',
    },
    styles: [
   {markerOptions:{ iconName:"star"}}
  ]                                        
});
```